# Insert into a row at specific position into SQL server table with PK

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert, rows

I want to insert a row into a SQL server table at a specific position. For example my table has 100 rows and I want to insert a new row at position 9. But the ID column which is PK for the table already has a row with ID 9. How can I insert a row at this position so that all the rows after it shift to next position?

Answer (score 15):

Relational tables have no 'position'. As an *optimization*, an index will sort rows by the specified key, if you wish to insert a row at a specific rank in the key order, insert it with a key that sorts in that rank position. In your case you'll have to update all rows with a value if ID greater than 8 to increment ID with 1, then insert the ID with value 9:

```
UPDATE TABLE table SET ID += 1 WHERE ID >= 9;
INSERT INTO TABLE (ID, ...) VALUES (9, ...);
```

Needless to say, there cannot possibly be any sane reason for doing something like that. If you would truly have such a requirement, then you would use a composite key with two (or more) parts. Such a key would allow you to insert subkeys so that it sorts in the desired order. But much more likely your problem can be solved exclusively by specifying a correct ORDER BY, w/o messing with the physical order of the rows.

Another way to look at it is to reconsider what primary key means: the identifier of an entity, which does not change during that entity lifetime. Then your question can be rephrased in a way that makes the fallacy in your question more obvious:

> I want to change the content of the entity with ID 9 to some new
>   value. The old values of the entity 9 should be moved to the content
>   of entity with ID 10. The old content of entity with ID 10 should be
>   moved to the entity with ID 11... and so on and so forth. The old
>   content of the entity with the highest ID should be inserted as a new
>   entity.

Answer (score 6):

Usually you **do not** want to use primary keys this way. A *better approach* would be to create another column called 'position' or similar where you can keep track of your own ordering system.

To perform the shifting you could run a query like this:

```
UPDATE table SET id = id + 1 WHERE id >= 9
```

This do not work if your column uses auto_increment functionality.

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't control where the new row is inserted. Actually, you don't need to: use the `ORDER BY` clause on your `SELECT` statements to order the results the way you need.

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE  @duplicateTable4 TABLE (id int,data VARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO @duplicateTable4 VALUES (1,'not duplicate row')
INSERT INTO @duplicateTable4 VALUES (2,'duplicate row')
INSERT INTO @duplicateTable4 VALUES (3,'duplicate rows')
INSERT INTO @duplicateTable4 VALUES (4,'second duplicate row')
INSERT INTO @duplicateTable4 VALUES (5,'second duplicat rows')
DECLARE  @duplicateTable5 TABLE (id int,data VARCHAR(20))

insert into @duplicateTable5 select *from @duplicateTable4
delete from @duplicateTable4


declare @i int , @cnt int
set @i=1
set @cnt=(select count(*) from @duplicateTable5)
while(@i<=@cnt)
begin
if @i=1 
begin
insert into @duplicateTable4(id,data) select 11,'indian' 
insert into @duplicateTable4(id,data) select id,data from @duplicateTable5 where id=@i
end
else
insert into @duplicateTable4(id,data) select id,data from @duplicateTable5 where id=@i
set @i=@i+1
end


    select *from @duplicateTable4
```

Comment: this code can be for inserting values at particular position, in this i set position=1 where the new row value inserted at row position 1

Answer (score 1):

This kind of violates the purpose of a relational table, but if you need, it's not really that hard to do.

1) use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY NameOfColumnToSort ASC) AS Row` to make a column for the row numbers in your table.

2)  From here you can copy (using `SELECT columnsYouNeed INTO` ) the before and after portions of the table into two separate tables (based on which row number you want to insert your values after) using a `WHERE Row < ##` and `Row >= ##` statement respectively.

3)  Next you drop the original table using `DROP TABLE`.

4)  Then you use a `UNION` for the before table, the row you want to insert (using a single explicitly defined `SELECT` statement without anything else), and the after table.  By now you have two `UNION` statements for 3 separate select clauses.  Here you can just wrap this in a `SELECT INTO FROM` clause calling it the name of your original table.

5) Last, you `DROP TABLE` the two tables you made.

This is similar to how an `ALTER TABLE` works.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO customers
(customer_id, last_name, first_name)
SELECT employee_number AS customer_id, last_name, first_name
FROM employees
WHERE employee_number < 1003;
```

FOR MORE REF: https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/insert.php