# How to Insert a new record in the middle of any table

Tags: sql-server

I want to insert a row into a SQL server table at a specific position. For example my table has 100 rows and also I have a field named LineNumber,I want to insert a new row after line number 9. But the ID column which is PK for the table already has a row with LineNumber 9. So now I need a new row with the line number 9 or 10 so that the ID field has to be updated automatically. How can I insert a row at this position so that all the rows after it shift to next position?

Comment: Tables are inherently unsorted, so you can't insert a record "in the middle". Can you rephrase your question?

Comment: Is this just a one time deal or something you need to do periodically?

Comment: Give sample data please.

Comment: you don't insert in a position, you read out in the order you require and have a field that can be used for ordering. In your case, don't use the primary key if you want to change the order of things over time.

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate question of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6962867/insert-into-a-row-at-specific-position-into-sql-server-table-with-pk

Comment: Using PKs for anything else other than uniquely identifying row is a very bad practice. If you need an ordering column, pls add one.

Comment: Are you working in test or production?

Comment: I need to do this periodically.. I am working in test@John

Answer (score 6):

Don't modify the primary key, that is not a good way to modify the order of your output now that you have a new record you want to insert.

Add a new column on to the table to hold your order. Then you can copy the primary key values in to that column if that's your current order before making the required changes for the new row.

Sample that you should be able to copy and paste and run as is:

I've added `orderid` column, which you will need to do with default null values.

```
DECLARE @OrderTable AS TABLE
    (
      id INT ,
      val VARCHAR(5) ,
      orderid INT
    )

INSERT  INTO @OrderTable
        ( id, val, orderid )
VALUES  ( 1, 'aaa', NULL )
        ,
        ( 2, 'bbb', NULL )
        ,
        ( 3, 'ddd', NULL )

SELECT  *
FROM    @OrderTable

-- Produces:
/*
id  val orderid
1   aaa NULL
2   bbb NULL
3   ddd NULL
*/

-- Update the `orderid` column to your existing order:

UPDATE  @OrderTable
SET     orderid = id

SELECT  *
FROM    @OrderTable

-- Produces:
/*
id  val orderid
1   aaa 1
2   bbb 2
3   ddd 3
*/

-- Then you want to add a new item to change the order:

DECLARE @newVal AS NVARCHAR(5) = 'ccc'
DECLARE @newValOrder AS INT = 3

-- Update the table to prepare for the new row:

UPDATE  @OrderTable
SET     orderid = orderid + 1
WHERE   orderid >= 3

-- this inserts ID = 4, which is what your primary key would do by default
-- this is just an example with hard coded value
INSERT  INTO @OrderTable
        ( id, val, orderid )
VALUES  ( 4, @newVal, @newValOrder )

-- Select the data, using the new order column:

SELECT  *
FROM    @OrderTable
ORDER BY orderid 

-- Produces:
/*
id  val orderid
1   aaa 1
2   bbb 2
4   ccc 3
3   ddd 4
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

What makes this difficult is that the column is a primary key.  If you can interact with the database when no one else is, then you can do this:

- Make the column no longer a primary key.
- Run a command like this:

> ```
> UPDATE MyTable
>     SET PrimaryColumnID = PrimaryColumnID + 1
> WHERE PrimaryColumnID > 8
> ```

- Insert the row with the appropriate PrimaryColumnID (9).
- Restore the column to being the primary key.

Obviously, this probably wouldn't be good with a large table.  You could create a new primary key column and switch it, then fix the values, then switch it back.

Comment: not good advice to simply "make the column no longer a primary key", many things could rely on the primary key, so what will you do for anything that references the primary key in a linked table?

Comment: @Tanner Just momentarily.  I'm assuming the table can be worked with in isolation, of course.

Comment: @tanner Have you never done this in a test database?  I certainly have.  You make a table for the 50 states, then realize you don't have them quite in alphabetical order, so you drop the primary key, renumber them, then add the Primary key back in.  Then when you copy to live, it's ordered correctly.

Comment: Do you also update all of the data that had a foreign key to this table? To expand upon your example, if there was a table of counties.  This now points to an incorrect state.

Comment: @Steven Good point.  However, I'm, of course, assuming there are no foreign keys on the table.  It sounds like a lookup table to me, having just 100 rows.

Comment: @JohnPasquet the OP didn't state, so I would never give dangerous advise, worth checking though.

Comment: Why would you need an identity for a table of US states? The state code is a perfectly solid primary key.

Comment: @SeanLange Yes... I was merely using it as an example.  I could have used days of the week,  months of the year, signs of the zodiac, planets of the solar system, moons of jupiter...

Answer (score -1):

Two steps, first update LineNumber

```
UPDATE
    table
SET
    LineNumber = LineNumber + 1
WHERE
    LineNumber>9
```

Then do your insert

```
INSERT INTO table
(LineNumber, ...) VALUES (10, .....)
```

Comment: OP states this field is a primary key so this won't work as is as 10 may already be taken

Comment: I do agree that using the primary key for ordering is bad design