# How to push ID's down when INSERTing new element

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, sql-insert

Let's say I have an SQL database with this

ID: 1; Username: Admin
ID: 2; Username: John
ID: 3; Username: Bill
ID: 5; Username: Ray

And I want to insert a new element before John with an ID of 2 instead
How can I get a result of this?

ID: 1; Username: Admin
ID: ***2***; Username: ***NewUser***
ID: ***3***; Username: John
ID: ***4***; Username: Bill
ID: 5; Username: Ray

The server push John and Bill downwards in terms of ID's
How do I do this using SQL commands? Do it using reusable functions because my server will be using this function a lot

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6962867/insert-into-a-row-at-specific-position-into-sql-server-table-with-pk

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insert into a row at specific position into SQL server table with PK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6962867/insert-into-a-row-at-specific-position-into-sql-server-table-with-pk)

Comment: If this is what you want to do, you should reconsider whether a relational database is really the right fit for your project at all. :-(

Comment: Changing existing ids seems like a really bad idea.  In general, something called an "id" should be considered immutable.

Comment: The answers from kmoser won't work, since both of those are about Microsoft SQL Server and you have tagged MySQL; the SQL commands from these two platforms are not compatible and those commands will give syntax errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Strawberry and Gordon Linoff have also stated, this is a very bad idea.

You should not reuse IDs in your database. You risk corrupting your data and violating one of the general principals of database design. You may not even want to delete old data, instead mark it as unused or disabled (or perhaps outright removal is correct for your use case, but think carefully about the data integrity of other tables).

Shifting the ID is even more problematic, because you'll have to update any reference to the old ID in the process or you'll make a mess of your data. There are risks of concurrency issues and data corruption in the case an update fails.

Please do not do this.

However, if you insist, there are two steps. First, shift the IDs. You have to first update the ID for Bill, then John. Make sure you update any other tables, queries, bookmarks, or printed references to this ID number as well. Then you can insert the new user to the old ID 2, which is as easy as explicitly providing the actual ID to the INSERT function (or, since you said you're using phpMyAdmin, just enter that number in the Insert field instead of leaving it blank).

But seriously, don't do this.

Comment: This code is for a notepad. If the user wants to shift a note to be the first to be seen, I want to change the ID to 1 so it will be displayed first. That's why I want to shift the other ID's down

Comment: I would recommend having another column for sort order, which you can then adjust as needed. This will likely require multiple queries to cascade the rest of the items further down the list. If you need an ID column, it shouldn't change; having a separate column for sorting order would maintain your data integrity and still let you easily change the sorting. How exactly you would make all the changes to the sort order is a design decision that depends a lot on your application and is mostly an opinion question.